# How to make pytest fixture scope shared by 2 modules but not by other modules

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Say I have one fixture with setup,cleanup code.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def myfixture():
   my_setup()
   yield
   my_cleanup()
```

Now 2 test modules are using this fixture. `test_A.py`, `test_B.py`. I also have another module `test_C.py` which is not using this fixture.

Now I would like call `my_setup()` only once before executing `test_A.py` and `test_B.py` (Do not want to call it for each module). One solution is changing the scope of fixture to `session`. But the problem is that `my_cleanup()` is not called before executing `test_C.py`. `test_C.py` must be executed in clean state.

How should I organize (or setup) the fixture and modules in this case?

The apparent solution is to combine `test_A.py` and `test_B.py` into one but would like to keep them separated for maintainability.